# Generating a page with data without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, get, anchor

I have encountered the following problem while trying to build a mobile app that generates its content based on a MySQL database. 
My problem is that when I want to go from page"A" to page "B", page "B" is completely empty, unless page "B" is opened in a new tab, in which case it displays the requested content without any flaws.

The code that I use (simplified):

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
    <div data-role='header' data-position='fixed'>
        <a href='#home' class='ui-btn-right' data-icon= 'home' data-iconpos='notext'  data-direction='reverse'></a>
        <h2>Activities</h>
    </div>
    <?php
    //(I'll keep the login and connection code out since it is irrelevant to the problem)

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT profession FROM members",$mysql) or die("");
    $query_amount = mysql_query("SELECT richting, COUNT(*) AS aantal FROM sport GROUP BY profession",$mysql) or die("");
    $query_membernr = mysql_query("SELECT membernr FROM members",$mysql) or die("");


    while(list($r) = mysql_fetch_row($query_amount))
    {

       $profession[]=$r;

            print ("
            <div data-role='content'>
              <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='false' id='pag1'>
                        <li>
                        <a href='index.php?richtingstack=$r#2a'>
                        <img src='images/something.jpg' height='80' align='middle' />
                        <p><h2> 
                        $r
                        </h2></p>
                        </a>
                     </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed'><h2>Kies een activiteit</h2>
            </div>"
            ) ;


    }

    ?>


</div>
```

This page (page"A") works perfectly and is generated by menas of the requested data.
It creates a list of professions from all of the DB users. (the members)

When someone presses one of the buttons in this list, it should go to a page (without reloading the entire app) with a list of members to who this profession applies. This page is page 2a, and is combined with a GETvariable.

For some reason, when I click one of these buttons, page #2a apears, but is completely void of content, apart from the header and footer, both of which are ofcourse not generated.

HOWEVER, if I rightclick one of the buttons and open the link in a new tab (reloading the app in a different tab, so to say) it works perfectly. I would really apprieciate it if someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong so that I can proceed.

Comment: why u r not doing this by ajax

Comment: And please try to tidy the code, the question looks a bit messy, so we can see it properly :P

Comment: The reason i'm not using Ajax is bassically because i have never used it before. I was hoping it would not be neccesary to use it, but since it seems to be inevitable, i'm going to try. Also: thank you for the feedback ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is not able to create content after runtime.

What you're searching for is AJAX (Async JavaScript and XML). Basically, it allows you to pull content from everywhere without having to reload the page. The client-side part is pure javascript. You can, for example, load the page http://yourdoma.in/index.php?tab=B and then replace your `div data-role="content"` with the text from that page.

Personally, i prefer using jQuery for AJAX because it will get pretty annoying to write and read with all the error-handling you would have to do with pure javascript. You can find the jQuery AJAX-Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). Or, if you want to go with pure javascript, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a dynamic site without reloading, use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can simply use Ajax which help you without reload a page. Suppose like this

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "post",
    data: data of you want,
    success: function(content){
        $("#B").html(content);
    },
    error:function(){

        $("#B").html('Content loaded problem');
    }
});
```